How to remove all <td> style of a specific table?
I have this table "wordTable". Each <td> has an id.
<table id="wordTable">
<tr>
<td id="1">ac</td>  <td id="2">bd</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="3">bf</td>  <td id="4">uy</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="5">ca</td><td></td>
</tr>
</table>

Some <td> got its style changed ramdomly. For example
document.getElementById("1").style.color ="red";

document.getElementById("3").style.color ="blue";

document.getElementById("2").style.color ="green";

How to remove all  style of table "wordTable" so that the table becomes to its original state?
Maybe something like this  document.getElementById('wordTable').TD. removeStyle();

This guy has asked many similar question on SO today!

You can remove the inline style of each  element within the table by looping through all  elements and setting their style attribute to an empty string.
Demo:


document.getElementById("1").style.color ="red";

document.getElementById("3").style.color ="blue";

document.getElementById("2").style.color ="green";


//get all <td> elements within the table with id 'wordTable'
var tdElements = document.querySelectorAll('#wordTable td');

//loop through each <td> element and remove its inline style
tdElements.forEach(function(td) {
    td.style = '';
});
<table id="wordTable">
  <tr>
    <td id="1">ac</td>  <td id="2">bd</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="3">bf</td>  <td id="4">uy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="5">ca</td><td></td>
  </tr>
</table>



